# Protecting routes without authGuard

Tags: routes, angular5

I have two types of users: Admin and normal user and I am using a micro-service concept so I have two Angular apps. App 1 is for Login, if success then redirect to url of App 2. I've already used authguard to prevent from unwanted access in the Login App. But in the App 2, unable to do this idea cause it's an external application.

Those are defined routes for App 2 in `app-routing.module.ts:`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile/:idC', component: AccountComponent },
  { path: 'admin/list', component: ListComponent }, 
]
```

I want to protect admin route from normal users also protect a user from other by clicking the specific url on the browser.

I tried to use JWT token but not working cause I'm not using back-end API with endpoint of /api/auth.

So any idea of protecting routes from manually edited on url browser, is welcome!

Comment: How are you determining who is an admin user vs. normal user? Do you have some object in memory representing the user that has details about the current user? Ultimately you will need some way of getting those details, which you can then use in your auth guard to protect your routes.

Comment: from Login App, we get data from put credentials and then compare the determined role. But I don't have authentication function in the second App cause those two applications are communicating with each other. It's a way of micro-service system. The issue is how to do this.